# How to initialize a View Controllers outlets inside of a Second View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How would I access a second view controllers IBOutlets from with in a second view controller? In my situation I initialize a current view controller with a statement like this.

`let eqController = EqualizerViewController()`

But although this statement works, when referencing an outlet from `eqController`, it succeeds at build time but fails at run time because he outlets are nil. How would I initialize those outlets from within the current view controller? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot initialize an object designed in Interface Builder with the default initializer `()`. It will return a new instance which is not the instance in IB and therefore doesn't ever connect the outlets. And even if this worked the outlets are not connected until `viewDidLoad` is called

Answer (score 1):

You can't access outlets because they are nil until the Vc loads , so inside the secondVC

```
class SecondVc:UIViewController {
   var sendedStr = ""  
}
```

//

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondId") as! SecondVc
vc.sendedStr = ""
// here  present / push
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to initialize a view controller to present, you would want to use the storyboard instead of doing the `let eqController = EqualizerViewController()`.

Try this instead:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let eqController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "eqController") as? EqualizerViewController
```

But you will also need to update the view controller's identifier in the storyboard, as shown below:
[image]

Comment: I’m not planning to present it, but rather just access information from the view controller, is there any way to do that?

Comment: What kind of information would you access from the view controller that wouldn't already be available outside of that view controller? If the logic is that tightly coupled to the controller, perhaps it should be abstracted into a place where it could be injected into the controller that you need to.